# Не работает кнопка Primefaces

Tags: glassfish, jsf, primefaces

Доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с следующей проблемой. Почему-то не срабатывает кнопка в приложении. Прошу объяснить, в чем может быть 'заковыка'

Фрагмент формы(Предшествует <_h:form>)

```
<p:panel>
<p:commandButton value="Проверить" actionListener="#{newObject.updatePreview()}" update="screenshotCamera" type="button"/>
<br/>
<p:graphicImage id="screenshotCamera" cache="false" url="#{newObject.JPGLink}" width="120px" height="120px" alt="Не удается подключиться к камере. Проверьте настройки" />
<br/>
<h:outputText value="Если изображения нет, то что-то не так в настройках. Перепроверьте, или обратитесь в службу поддержки." />
<h:panelGrid columns="1">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputText value="Отображать на карте?"/>
        <p:inputSwitch value="#{newObject.createdCamera.showInTheMap}" onLabel="Да" offLabel="Нет" />
        <h:outputText value="Выберете объект :" />
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{newObject.selectedFacility}" effect="fold" >
            <c:forEach var="facility" items="#{newObject.facilitysForSelect}" >
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{facility.title}" itemValue="#{facility}" />
            </c:forEach>                                            
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <p:commandButton value="Все верно!" action="#{newObject.createCamera}" actionListener="#{viewController.setCurrentContent('cameras')}" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

Фрагмент бина:

```
public void updatePreview(){
    createdCamera.setJPGLink("http://"+cameraLogin+":"+cameraPassword+"@"+cameraWanIP+":"+cameraPort+"/Streaming/channels/1/picture?snapShotImageType=JPEG");
    System.out.println("Link updated");
}
```

Так вот консоль молчит.Ни ошибок, ни сообщений.Как в консоле, так и в

```
 p:messages autoupdate="true"
```

Как или чем дебажить?

Comment: Информации недостаточно для того, чтобы дать однозначный ответ, т.к. приведена неполная JSF-страница и неполный Java-класс бина. Источники проблемы могут быть разные, и не имея более полной информации, можно лишь делать предположения, а не давать конкретные ответы. Если JSF-страница слишком большая, сделайте её копию, которая не содержит лишней информации, позволяя при этом воспроизвести ошибку.

Answer (score 2):

```
<p:commandButton type="button"/>
```

> **PrimeFaces 5.2 user guide, p 112**
>
> Push buttons are used to execute custom javascript without causing an
>   ajax/non-ajax request. To create a push button set type as "button".

Собственно `type="button"` служит для предотвращения отправки запроса на сервер при нажатии.